# How to determine application's method count?

Tags: java, android

I'm encountering issues with my application having too many methods.

In the last post in the below link, a poster posts the method count for his application (broken down by package). I unable to find how I can get this information for my application, any suggestions?

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20814

Comment: If you're using protobufs or something that generates lots of methods, you probably need to enable Proguard to remove unused methods.

Answer (score 31):

I use

```
cat build/dex/debug/classes.dex | head -c 92 | tail -c 4 | hexdump -e '1/4 "%d\n"'
```

I get `55176`. 64k limit is coming :D

Comment: You can run this on a terminal on Linux or on OSX.

Comment: Ok i was trying in windows.So for Windows,I guess I should use KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin

Comment: just run it in your main "app" folder ("build" folder is created there) on Linux/OsX

Comment: build/dex/debug/classes.dex: No such file or directory, tried running it from by project base folder, app, build

Comment: Try to locate your `.dex` files with something like: `find . | grep ".dex"`

Comment: In Windows, it is often in `build/intermediates/transforms/dex/release/folders/1000/1f/main/classes.dex` and `.../debug/...` but searching for `*.dex` as @IvanMorgillo suggests will get where _your_ build system put it.

Answer (score 13):

To get a method-count report on every build, do this:

in `app/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.7.3'
    }
}

// make sure this line comes *after* you apply the Android plugin
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```

It will show the number of methods per package, for your own project and the libraries you use.

From: https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin

Comment: where to look for the output ?

Comment: after your build it's at the bottom of your build log. ("Gradle Console" on the bottom right of Android Studio)

Comment: I find it helpful to look at the HTML page generated in `app/build/outputs/dexcount/{$variant}/index.html`.

Comment: The visualisation produced from this plugin is awesome

Answer (score 6):

You can use APK Analyzer in the Android studio

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool [APK method count](http://inloop.github.io/apk-method-count/) which counts the number of methods in your apk.

There is also a service [methodscount.com](http://www.methodscount.com/) to check method count of libraries. This  service also has [Android Studio/IntelliJ plugin](http://www.methodscount.com/plugins) that parses your Android library dependencies and shows the methods count as an handy hint.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use a static code analyzer; [Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html), for example, is free SW and has the count you're searching for.

Or if you prefer to do it without additional plugins, try doing this (Eclipse only):

- Press Ctrl-H (Search), then select the "Java Search" tab (if it doesn't appear click on the "Customize..." button at the lower left corner)
- Put * in the search box
- Select "Method" in the "Search For" fieldset
- Select "Declarations" in the "Limit To" fieldset
- Select "Sources" in the "Search In" fieldset
- Select "Workspace" in the "Scope" fieldset
- Click on "Search"

After the search is complete you should see a "XXXX declarations in..." message in the search view and that will be your result.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @jbird the eclipse method should be platform independent

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaNCSS to get such statistics. It is available here: http://www.kclee.de/clemens/java/javancss/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin? Shows you the number of methods per package graphically and/or text.

Answer (score 0):

To find and Android app method count with or without **multidex** support use:

```
find | grep classes.dex | xargs -I {} hexdump -e '"%d {}\n"' -s 0x58 -n 4 {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already built application, then you can use dexdump (AOSP tool) for this:

```
# Get the number of classes.
dexdump -h ApkName.apk | grep "^class_idx" | wc -l
# Get the number of methods.
dexdump -h ApkName.apk | grep "method_idx" | wc -l
```